# Trying to get property of non-object in Codeigniter template

Tags: php, codeigniter

I make simple template use code codeigniter. 
my code like this.......

This is *template.php* class

```
class Template {

protected $_ci;

function _construct() {
    $this->_ci=&get_instance();
}

function display($template, $data = null) {

    $data['_content'] = $this->_ci->load->view($template, $data, TRUE);
    $data['_header'] = $this->_ci->load->view('template/header', $data, TRUE);
    $data['_top_menu'] = $this->_ci->load->view('template/menu', $data, TRUE);
    $data['_right_menu'] = $this->_ci->load->view('template/sidebar', $data, TRUE);
    $this->_ci->load->view('/template.php', $data);
}


}
```

and this is my controller *welcome.php* class

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); //you always have to call parent's constructor before ANYTHING
    $this->load->library('template');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index() {
    $this->template->display('welcome_message');
}

function contoh_parameter() {
    $this->template->display('view_parameter', array('judul' => 'Judul View'));
}

}
```

and this is my view class, *welcome_message.php* class

```
   <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

   <div id="body">
    <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

    <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
    <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

    <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
    <code>application/controllers/welcome.php</code>

    <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
</div>

<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
```

But I get error like this :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/template.php

Line Number: 25
```

Sorry I am still a newbie in codeigniter and php. Please help me.

Comment: I think your constructor only has a single `_`. It should be two underscores: `__constructor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your construct method isn't right it should be `__construct` instead of `_construct`

Second you use `$this->_ci->load->view('/template.php', $data);` when you load a view you shouldn't use any slash at the beginning path up to view directory is available to CI. So if your view file is **`template.php`** in CI view folder then use it in this way `$this->_ci->load->view('template', $data);`. Also you use `.php` extension CI self adds that extension.